# passing value from javascript to partial view in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

the given below is my script

```
var selectedImage;

function select(image) {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  var index = 0, length = images.length;

  for (; index < length; index++) {
    images[index].classList.remove('selected');
  }

  selectedImage = image.id;
  image.classList.add('selected');

  var image = document.getElementById(selectedImage);
  var audioId = image.getAttribute('data-audio')
  var audioElement = document.getElementById(audioId);
}
```

Now i want to pass the value of "audio element (which contains the Url of an audio fetched from database)" to another function which is defined in partial view. How to do this? please help.

Comment: Your partial view is already loaded when your javascript function is executed ?

Comment: Fix your code. That for loop is missing its first statement. Also, post your partial view.

Comment: nope partial view is displayed on button click event. actually what i really want to do is to check which image is being clicked by the user and then on button click its respective  audio url for the clicked image is being sent to another view which take that audio url as an argument and perform some  function on it.                                                                                           int fileplay_handle = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(audioElement.value);